# Is there a formal way to access those document in /usr/share/doc?

Tags: command-line, documentation

[image]

I find there are many documents for a software that I've installed. I know we can show man document by using `man` command.

How about others, is there any formal way to access those document, or I have to CD to the directory and vi it ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just copy the text here and apply formatting.

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/157996/utilities-for-find-open-linux-usr-share-docs

Comment: I doubt there is a way for the examples, but if that's a plain  text , use paging utilities like `less`, and for pdf . . . well, `evince` or any other pdf reader will do.